# Laravel and Angular url prefix issue with apache

Tags: php, angularjs

I created an app with Laravel and angular. On development The app works good in `php artisan serve` in `localhost:8000`.

if i copied the project folder and paste in **www** of lamp or wamp then i need to use `localhost/projectname/public`. To load the css and js i use `<base href="/projectname/public/">` in my main html.

But my urls and angular templates still miss the `projectname/public`. if I click a url it goes to `localhost\url`. How to prefix url in angular? or is there another way to work this out?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to fix this.

First is laravel homestead. This is perfect for laravel projects. for more information about homestead go [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead)

The other option is to setup a virtual host on your wamp server. For more info about this go [here](http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp)